# How to extract color from span which is in p tag from an html using JSOUP?

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

```
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
        <p>My mother has 
        <span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">blue</span>
        eyes and my father has 
        <span style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">
        dark green</span> 
        eyes.</p>
<h3>This is another heading<h3>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

"My mother has **blue** eyes and my father has **dark green** eyes". I want to parse this sentance using JSOUP and print the same with bold and coloured text on an android textview. Here "blue" is bold and in blue color. "Dark Green" is bold and in color.

I need to parse the above html code and need to display like this :

This is a heading
My mother has **blue** eyes and my father has **dark green** eyes
This is another heading
This is a paragraph

Below is my program. Considering  Document doc == get above html;

```
    Elements eHeadder = doc.select("*");
    for (Element eHead : eHeadder) {
    String tag = eHead.tagName();
    if (tag.equals("p")) {
    String pText = eHead.text();
    tv.setText(pText);
    }else if(tag.equals("h2")){
      String pText = eHead.text();
      tv.setText(pText);
      }else if(tag.equals("h3")){
      String pText = eHead.text();
      tv.setText(pText);
      }
   }
```

1. Can anybody help me with a solution?
2. I am confused in using doc.select("p") and doc.select("p").first; Could you explain this also when you give a reply?

Comment: Hm, I can't understand what you like to do. Where the "h2" is comming from. Somehow I don't get how the title and your question belongs together

Comment: Ah, you like to parse css values?

Comment: Please comment what you need, then I'll try to help you

Comment: Yes. you are right! I need to parse a html page. Above codes are just a part of my program. the if statement parse all the datas in p tag. Similarly if I add another, if else(tag.equals("h2")) I can parse all the datas in h2. But I need to get the datas in <span> and span is inside <p>. You can see the html I posted.

Comment: Can you check the last post. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you ment?

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final String html = "<p>My mother has\n" +
            "<span style=\"color:blue;font-weight:bold\">blue</span>\n" +
            "eyes and my father has\n" +
            "<span style=\"color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold\">\n" +
            "dark green</span>\n" +
            "eyes.</p>\n" +
            "<h2>Mr. <span style=\"color:green\">Foobar</span></h2>";

    final Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);

    final Elements textNodes = document.select("p,h2");

    for (final Element element : textNodes)
    {
        System.out.println("Found: " + element.text());

        System.out.println("\t Neasted Spawns:");
        for (final Element span : element.select("span"))
        {
            System.out.println("\t\t css: " + span.attr("style"));
        }
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
Found: My mother has blue eyes and my father has dark green eyes.
     Neasted Spawns:
         css: color:blue;font-weight:bold
         css: color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold
Found: Mr. Foobar
     Neasted Spawns:
         css: color:green
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Christian Schneider. That worked!!!. I was not knowing that I can use multiple tags in select statement. The logic you used here saved lots of lines of codes!!! Thanks again!!!